# Property of probabilities to add up to 1 : conditional case

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I was wondering in the case of conditional distributions, where let's say we have $P(X|Y)$, if we fix $Y = a$, would the probabilities of $P(X|Y=a)$ for all values of X necessarily all add up to 1? If so then why?

Additionally, our professor also told us that if we had the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$, then when we are trying to derive $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ we are essentially fixing y, and looking at a slice of our pdf, and scaling that so that the integral adds up to 1. I did not quite understand this, and if someone could give me some more geometric intuition that would be super helpful. Thank you!

Comment: You ask "would the probabilities necessarily add up to 1" and I do not know what that means.  What "probabilities" are you talking about? Are you assuming $X$ is a discrete random variable?  What is meant by $P[X|Y]$?  Do you mean $P[X=x|Y=a]$?

Comment: @Michael Edited it

Comment: What if you make the problem simpler: Let $X$ be a Gaussian random variable with mean 0 and variance 1, so $X \sim N(0,1)$.  So $X$ can take any of the uncountably infinite values in $\mathbb{R}$.  It does not make sense to ask "would the probabilities for all vlaues of $X$ necessarily add to 1" since $P[X=x]=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, and we can only sum over an at-most countably infinite number of terms anyway.  Here we talk of probability density function for $X$, not probability mass function.

Comment: Can't it be either? Wouldn't it be true for either the discrete or the continuous case?

Comment: Do you have any background on integration theory or measure theory? Your question can be answered through the lens of measurability. Anyways, if you want to have a grasp on the result, think on the Bayesian approach, i.e., take a random variable $X \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma)$ and "model" $\sigma$ as an RV, e.g. $\sigma \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ then it's easy to see, that for each value of $\sigma$ you'll have a distribution for $P(X \mid \sigma)$ integrating 1 (or "summing" to one, note that $Y = \sigma$ in this case).

Comment: Yes, of course $\int p(y|x = a)\ dy =1$... always.  What this means is that given some value $x=a$, you are guaranteed to get *some* value of $y$, and thus the integral is $1$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork But why must this be the case? I really don't see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional distribution of $X$ given some event $A$ **is still a probability distribution**, so yes, the "probabilities must sum to $1$." For instance, if $X$ is a discrete random variable, then
$$\sum_x P(X=x \mid A) = 1$$
where the sum is over all values $X$ can take. Here, $A$ can be any event, such as $\{Y=a\}$ for some other random variable $Y$.

---

In the case where $(X,Y)$ has a joint density $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, what your professor is saying is that the conditional density of $X$ given $Y=y_0$ looks kind of like the function $g(x) := f_{X,Y}(x,y_0)$ (this is the "slice of the joint PDF" where the second component is fixed at $y_0$). However, we do not have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(x) \, dx = 1$ necessarily since $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y_0) \, dx = f_Y(y_0)$. But if we divide $g$ by this quantity (this is the "rescaling") we can make the integral equal to one. The conditional density ends up being this resulting function: $f_{X \mid Y=y_0}(x) = \frac{f_{X,Y}(x,y_0)}{f_Y(y_0)}$ which does satisfy $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X \mid Y=y_0}(x) \, dx = 1$.

[Proving why this actually is the conditional density is a bit technical, but I guess your professor is just trying to give you intuition. It resembles the discrete case $P(X=x \mid Y=y_0) = \frac{P(X=x, Y=y_0)}{P(Y=y_0)}$.]